# Assign jquery plugin to dropdown not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an audio player that have 4 dropdown lists each depends on each other to get the right mp3 file, the jquery code works fine until i assign a plugin to the dropdown called (fancyspinbox) to look better.
**The problem is the dropdown dont update its value though its triggered successfully.**

[image]

Kindly find my code below

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ddbibletype').fancyspinbox();
    $('#ddtestament').fancyspinbox();
    $("#booksdd").fancyspinbox();
    $("#chapterdd").fancyspinbox();
});
$("#ddtestament").change(function () {
    var options = {};
    options.url = '@Url.Action("GetBooks", "Home")';
    options.type = "POST";
    if ($("#ddtestament option:selected").index() == 0)
        options.data = JSON.stringify({ testament: 'OT' });
    else
        options.data = JSON.stringify({ testament: 'NT' });
    options.dataType = "json";
    options.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    options.success = function (jsonResult) {
        $("#booksdd").empty();
        $("#chapterdd").empty();
        var jb = $(jsonResult.jbooks);
        var jc = $(jsonResult.jchapters);
        for (var i = 0; i < jb.length; i++) {
           $("#booksdd").append("<option>" + jb[i] + "</option>");
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < jc.length; i++) {
            $("#chapterdd").append("<option>" + jc[i] + "</option>");
        }
        $("#booksdd").change();
    };
    options.error = function () { alert("Error retrieving Books!"); };
    $.ajax(options);
});

$("#booksdd").change(function () {

        var options = {};
        options.url = '@Url.Action("GetChapters", "Home")';
        options.type = "POST";
        if ($("#ddtestament option:selected").index() == 0)
            options.data = JSON.stringify({ bookID: $("#booksdd option:selected").index() });
        else
            options.data = JSON.stringify({ bookID: ($("#booksdd option:selected").index() + 39) });
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        options.success = function (chapters) {
            $("#chapterdd").empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < chapters.length  ; i++) {
                $("#chapterdd").append("<option>" + chapters[i] + "</option>");
            }
            $("#chapterdd").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#chapterdd").change();
        };
        options.error = function () { alert("Error retrieving chapters!"); };
        $.ajax(options);

});

$("#chapterdd").change(function () {

        var options = {};
        options.url = '@Url.Action("GetTrackPath", "Home")';
        options.type = "POST";
        if ($("#ddtestament option:selected").index() == 0)
            options.data = JSON.stringify({ bibleType: $("#ddbibletype option:selected").index(), bookID: $("#booksdd option:selected").index() + 1, chapterNum: $("#chapterdd option:selected").index() + 1 });
        else
            options.data = JSON.stringify({ bibleType: $("#ddbibletype option:selected").index(), bookID: ($("#booksdd option:selected").index() + 40), chapterNum: $("#chapterdd option:selected").index() + 1 });
        options.dataType = "json";
        options.contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        options.success = function (trackpath) {
            var audio = $('#bibleplayer');
            $('#mpsource').attr('src', trackpath);
            audio[0].pause();
            audio[0].load();//suspends and restores all audio element
            audio[0].oncanplaythrough = audio[0].play();
        };
        options.error = function () {
            alert("Error retrieving Books!");
        };
        $.ajax(options);



});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using this fancyspingbox? https://github.com/mayakokits/jquery.fancyspinbox

There is no mention there of needing to add different event listeners, but they do mention "If you need to access the spinbox element, use the element object.". Possibly that is the solution

ie this line

```
$("#ddtestament").change(function () {
```

becomes

```
$("#ddtestament").element.change(function () {
```

or

```
$($("#ddtestament").element).change(function () {
```

as do the other similar lines.

Comment: thanks for your reply but it didnt work any suggestions. the problem is in the empty , append functions the change function is working